# HSQL function useful for datamasking

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb

Does anybody know how to perform data masking using existing functions (similar to random function in oracle) in HSQL db.

Comment: Do you mean dbms_random.random procedure? And what means data masking? Put some samples, examples desired output. Or you may be downvoted...

Comment: It's just that I wanted to jumble the characters of the names(Mask the original data). I've used soundex and reverse functions in HSQL. Thank you though :)